# Iterate through a html file and extract data to CSV file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, playwright

I have searched high and low for a solution, but non have quite fit what I need to do.

I have an html page that is saved, as a file, lets call it sample.html and I need to extract recurring json data from it. An example file is as follows:
I need to get the info from these files regulary, so the amount of objects change every time, an object would be considered as "{"SpecificIdent":2588,"SpecificNum":29,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false}"
I need to get each of the values to a CSV file, with column headings being SpecificIdent, SpecificNum, Meter, Power, WPower, Snumber, isI. The associated data would be the rows from each.

I apologize if this is a basic question in Python, but I am pretty new to it and cannot fathom the best way to do this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

A

```
<html><head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[{"SpecificIdent":2588,"SpecificNum":29,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":3716,"SpecificNum":39,"Meter":1835,"Power":11240.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"0703-403548","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":6364,"SpecificNum":27,"Meter":7768,"Power":29969.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"467419","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":6583,"SpecificNum":51,"Meter":7027,"Power":36968.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521248","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":6612,"SpecificNum":57,"Meter":12828,"Power":53918.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1509-534327","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":7139,"SpecificNum":305,"Meter":6264,"Power":33101.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521204","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":7551,"SpecificNum":116,"Meter":0,"Power":21569.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521252","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":7643,"SpecificNum":56,"Meter":7752,"Power":40501.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521200","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":8653,"SpecificNum":49,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":9733,"SpecificNum":142,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":10999,"SpecificNum":20,"Meter":7723,"Power":6987.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1608-625534","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":12086,"SpecificNum":24,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":14590,"SpecificNum":35,"Meter":394,"Power":10941.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"BN1905-944799","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":14954,"SpecificNum":100,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"517163","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":14995,"SpecificNum":58,"Meter":0,"Power":38789.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1444-511511","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":15245,"SpecificNum":26,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"430149","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":18824,"SpecificNum":55,"Meter":8236,"Power":31358.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"0703-310839","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":20745,"SpecificNum":41,"Meter":0,"Power":60963.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1447-517260","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":31584,"SpecificNum":11,"Meter":0,"Power":3696.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"467154","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":32051,"SpecificNum":40,"Meter":7870,"Power":13057.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1608-625593","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":32263,"SpecificNum":4,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":33137,"SpecificNum":132,"Meter":5996,"Power":26650.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"459051","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":33481,"SpecificNum":144,"Meter":4228,"Power":16136.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1603-617807","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":33915,"SpecificNum":145,"Meter":5647,"Power":3157.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1518-549610","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":36051,"SpecificNum":119,"Meter":2923,"Power":12249.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"135493","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":37398,"SpecificNum":21,"Meter":58,"Power":5540.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"BN1925-982761","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":39024,"SpecificNum":50,"Meter":7217,"Power":38987.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1445-511599","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":39072,"SpecificNum":59,"Meter":5965,"Power":32942.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521199","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":40601,"SpecificNum":9,"Meter":0,"Power":59655.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1447-517150","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":40712,"SpecificNum":37,"Meter":0,"Power":5715.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1502-525840","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":41596,"SpecificNum":53,"Meter":8803,"Power":60669.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1503-527155","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":50276,"SpecificNum":30,"Meter":2573,"Power":4625.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1545-606334","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":51712,"SpecificNum":69,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":56140,"SpecificNum":10,"Meter":5169,"Power":26659.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1547-609024","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":56362,"SpecificNum":6,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":58892,"SpecificNum":113,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":65168,"SpecificNum":5,"Meter":12739,"Power":55833.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521284","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":65255,"SpecificNum":60,"Meter":5121,"Power":27784.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521196","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":65665,"SpecificNum":47,"Meter":11793,"Power":47576.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1509-534315","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":65842,"SpecificNum":8,"Meter":10783,"Power":46428.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1509-534401","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":65901,"SpecificNum":22,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":65920,"SpecificNum":17,"Meter":9316,"Power":38242.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1509-534360","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":66119,"SpecificNum":43,"Meter":12072,"Power":52157.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521259","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":70018,"SpecificNum":34,"Meter":11172,"Power":49706.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1449-521285","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":71388,"SpecificNum":54,"Meter":6947,"Power":36000.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1445-512406","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":71892,"SpecificNum":36,"Meter":15398,"Power":63691.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1447-517256","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":72600,"SpecificNum":38,"Meter":14813,"Power":62641.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1447-517189","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":73645,"SpecificNum":2,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":77208,"SpecificNum":28,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":77892,"SpecificNum":15,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":78513,"SpecificNum":31,"Meter":6711,"Power":36461.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"JE1445-511601","isI":false},{"SpecificIdent":79531,"SpecificNum":18,"Meter":0,"Power":0.0,"WPower":null,"SNumber":"","isI":false}]</pre></body></html>
```

I have tried examples from bs4, jsontoxml, and others, but I am sure there is a simple way to iterate and extract this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness python's standard library following way

```
import csv
import json
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data.strip():
            self.data = data

parser = MyHTMLParser()
with open("sample.html","r") as f:
    parser.feed(f.read())
with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['SpecificIdent', 'SpecificNum', 'Meter', 'Power', 'WPower', 'SNumber', 'isI']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(json.loads(parser.data))
```

which creates file starting with following lines

```
SpecificIdent,SpecificNum,Meter,Power,WPower,SNumber,isI
2588,29,0,0.0,,,False
3716,39,1835,11240.0,,0703-403548,False
6364,27,7768,29969.0,,467419,False
6583,51,7027,36968.0,,JE1449-521248,False
6612,57,12828,53918.0,,JE1509-534327,False
7139,305,6264,33101.0,,JE1449-521204,False
7551,116,0,21569.0,,JE1449-521252,False
7643,56,7752,40501.0,,JE1449-521200,False
8653,49,0,0.0,,,False
```

Disclaimer: this assumes JSON array you want is last text element which is not empty (i.e. contain at least 1 non-whitespace character).

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you for taking the time! Well explained with outputs, for someone that is lacking in the experience and logic, it is much appreciated! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library, called `BeautifulSoup`, that you could utilize to parse the whole HTML file:

```py
# pip install bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup(your-html)
```

From here on, you can perform any actions upon the html. In your case, you just need to find the `<pre>` element, and get its contents. This can be achieved easily:

```py
pre = html.body.find('pre')
text = pre.text
```

Finally, you need to parse the text, which it seems is JSON. You can do with Python's internal `json` library:

```py
import json

result = json.loads(text)
```

Now, we need to convert this to a CSV file. This could be done, using the `csv` library:

```py
import csv

with open('GFG', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=[
        "SpecificIdent",
        "SpecificNum",
        "Meter",
        "Power",
        "WPower",
        "SNumber",
        "isI"
    ])

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Finally, your code should look something like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

with open('raw.html', 'r') as f:
    raw = f.read()

html = BeautifulSoup(raw)
pre = html.body.find('pre')
text = pre.text
result = json.loads(text)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=[
        "SpecificIdent",
        "SpecificNum",
        "Meter",
        "Power",
        "WPower",
        "SNumber",
        "isI"
    ])

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```